# C# comparing strings ignoring both: whitespaces, CR etc and cases

Tags: c#, string

i want to compare 2 string in C#, but i need to ignore both things: whitespaces and case. I found 2 separate ways to do this. For case it is:

`if (string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)){}`

and for ignoring whitespaces it is:

`if (string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){}`

Is there any way to do this without creating new string, that will be ex. .toLower() but to make it in an if construction?

Comment: [`OrdinalIgnoreCase` doesn't ignore whitespace...?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9vbNZP)

Comment: How do strings looks like?

Comment: Note, if you want to ignore symbols as well as whitespace, [`CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=netframework-4.8) might work for you.

Comment: Title made sense... but with example of what you mean "ignoring whitespaces with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`" I'm totally lost. Consider [edit] the post with examples of what you expect to happen, in particular the second one.

Comment: Does this need to cater for Unicode and culture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use both `CompareOptions`, `IgnoreCase` and `IgnoreSymbols` if you add `|`.

**Example:**

```cs
string s1 = " A ";
string s2 = "a";
string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);
```

Be aware `IgnoreSymbols` doesn't only ignore Whitespaces but others as well. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=netframework-4.8) for more detail on the `CompareOptions`.

Comment: Note this will ignore things which aren't whitespace, such as punctuation.

Comment: Thanks will add that as well.

Comment: does it return bool or sth else?

Comment: it returns a number that is equal to 0 if it is equal you can add a check when you use if (... == 0) or != 0 respectively